# Thinking of a beloved so deeply

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes when someone is thinking of their beloved so deeply that they almost become addictive to these thoughts, or perhaps is overthinking about them so much so that they cannot get rid of these thoughts no matter what.

I tried googling "addictively" but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be a word according to Oxford dictionary.

The sentence in context goes like this:

> When was the last time you were lost in my thoughts as *addictively* as I be?

Comment: Addictively is a word: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/addictively

Comment: Not sure why so many dictionaries don't show the adverb from of addictive. They show all show "divisively", and "addictively" is more common than that both from Google search and Google NGram Viewer https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=addictively%2Cdivisively&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caddictively%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdivisively%3B%2Cc0 There are also other words that dictionaries don't show the "-ly" adverb form for, that are words and are used.

Comment: The key issue here is finding an adverb that fits the metaphor of being "lost." One may *act* addictively, but one is not "lost" that way.  Maybe "completely"? Also "..you were lost in my thoughts" doesn't seem to parse.  Do you mean "...lost in thoughts of me as completely as I am in thoughts of you?" "My thoughts" is not the same thing as "thoughts of me."

Comment: Yes, @remarkl I wish to frame the words so as to ask, "Do you also find yourself lost in my thoughts as deeply/obsessively/addictively as I find myself?"
However I wish to start the sentence with the same words as mentioned earlier, "When was the last time you..."

Answer (score 2):

"Addictively" is definitely an acceptable word. See my comments to your question.

> or perhaps is overthinking about them so much so that they cannot get
>   rid of these thoughts no matter what.

The word *obsessive* is often used for thoughts that someone can't stop thinking about, so they're addictive in a way. It can also be used to describe a person or the behavior of such a person.

[NGram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obsessive%20thoughts%2Cobsessive%20person%2C%20obsessive%20behaviour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobsessive%20thoughts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobsessive%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobsessive%20behaviour%3B%2Cc0) for: obsessive thoughts, obsessive person, obsessive behavior.

> obsessive
>   2.continually preoccupied with a particular activity, person, or thing
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obsessive)

Since you mentioned a beloved, maybe rapturous/ly would be an appropriate word.

> rapture
>  1 : an expression or manifestation of ecstasy or
>   passion
>  2a : a state or experience of being carried away by
>   overwhelming emotion
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rapturous)

Answer (score 0):

***obsessive (ly)***

> thinking about something or someone, or doing something, too much or all the time:

[-Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obsessive)

Although the tendency these days is to talk about Obsessive Compulsive Disorder (OCD), I would probably say that this is some sort of obsession.

Answer (score -1):

**Compulsively** has a sense of being overdone and/or out of your control. When you act compulsively, it's as if your mind compels you to do something whether you want to or not.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compulsive):

> of, relating to, caused by, or suggestive of **psychological compulsion or obsession**

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/compulsively):

> **too much** and in a way that shows you are **unable to stop**:

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compulsively):

> In a way that results from or relates to an **irresistible** urge.

Answer (score -1):

When was the last time you were lost in your thoughts as besottedly as I am?

Besot - to stupefy with drink.
Besotted - in a stupefied state caused by alcohol.

Now used more usually to describe a person in a non-logical state caused by continual obsessive thoughts of a person, that is often mistakenly called 'love'.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to EL&U. While your answer is a good start, could you possibly provide a source for your suggestion? It's kind of a requirement here for a good answer. Also, no mention of alcohol was mentioned in the Q.